# How to model a Power BI date table when the database date table has duplicates due to each client having their own calendar?

Tags: t-sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-modeling

In the database I have a date table. The date table has got a calendar for each client. So for example say there are 10 clients, and the calendar has dates for 5 years, then there are 10 * 5 * 365 records in this table.

Example:

```
+--------+------------+------+------+----------+--------+
| Client |    Date    | FYYR | FYWK | CORPFYYR | CORPWK |
+--------+------------+------+------+----------+--------+
| Costco | 01-06-2022 | 2023 |    1 |     2022 |     22 |
| Walmart| 01-06-2022 | 2022 |   22 |     2022 |     22 |
| Costco | 02-06-2022 | 2023 |    1 |     2022 |     22 |
| Walmart| 02-06-2022 | 2022 |   22 |     2022 |     22 |
| Costco | 03-06-2022 | 2023 |    1 |     2022 |     22 |
| Walmart| 03-06-2022 | 2022 |   22 |     2022 |     22 |
| Costco | 04-06-2022 | 2023 |    1 |     2022 |     22 |
| Walmart| 04-06-2022 | 2022 |   22 |     2022 |     22 |
+--------+------------+------+------+----------+--------+
```

When I import this table into Power BI, then it doesn't allow me to mark it as date table (due to duplicates).

Since it has duplicate dates, when I create a relationship from this table to the fact table, it gets created as a M:M relation (msdn documentation mentions that M:M reduces the model performance).

On the report I have a slicer (on client name from this date table) to ensure that only 1 client is selected, so that the calendar then doesn't have duplicates.

I cannot use DAX date/time intelligence function because this table cannot be marked as a date table.

To solve this I could create 5 date tables from that table, mark them all as date tables and connect all of them to the fact table. Then have 1 report page per client. But I don't want to do this as I don't want to create separate report page per client.

What is the correct way to model such a date table in this scenario via SQL or PowerQuery or PowerBI? The end goal being that the table can be marked as a date table so that I can use date/time intelligence DAX.

Comment: Can you mock up an example of the final report you plan to create. i.e. what would be in a slicer, what would be shown in a table, which columns would be shown?

Comment: Well, this is for enterprise reporting. So it needs to cater to all reporting requirements.

Comment: I understand but in order to help, I need to understand how you plan to visualise the data. What is the simplest report you would create based on the proposed model?

Comment: Say fact table has sales date, clientid and salesamount. There is a client table with clientid, clientname that connects to the fact table on clientid. And our date table links to fact table on date. The report will have slicer to choose calendar (client), another slicer to choose client from the dim table, and a table visual that has 3 columns: date, sum(salesamt), calculate(sum(salesamt), dateadd(date, -1, day). Another report may have the table visual as fiscalyear, fiscalweek, sum(salesamt)...

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Time intelligence functions won't work without a proper date table. In addition a many-to-many should be avoided if at all possible as it will make the rest of your DAX very complicated.
2. A date table is by definition just a dimension with no duplicates and a full range of dates covering an entire year. You can create this dimension from your fact table in PQ.

The real question is why does each client get their own calendar? What is the difference between client 1's calendar and client 2's calendar?

Many to many relationships are "limited" relationships and do not behave like normal one-to-many relationships in a whole host of ways (e.g. no blank row for missing dimension keys). It is a very detailed subject and you're best reading from the experts here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/strong-and-weak-relationships-in-power-bi/

Regarding having a different calendar table per client, I think I understand now and the solution might be complicated. If you only have a few clients, I would be tempted to create these calendars as additional columns of a standard date table. e.g. Date - Day - Month - Year - Etc - Client Type 1 FY Start, Client Type 2 FY Start

Ideally there is some commonality between each client so you can genericise the special columns as I have done with Client Type rather than individual client.

It is common in PBI to create dimension tables from a fact table. You do this by referencing the fact table, removing other columns, removing duplicates and then you are left with a dimension table to join to your fact table in the model.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the count of calendars, I recommend to abstract the different calendars from the customers. For example:

- Customer A uses Calendar A
- Customer B uses Calendar B
- Customer C uses Calendar A
- Customer C uses Calendar A

Then you should hopefully end up with just a couple of calendars.

In the next step I would add columns to the date table according to the calendars. If the calendars just differ in week information this would be WeekNumber, WeekYear and so on.

Example:

| DateKey | Week_C1 | WeekYear_C1 | WeekYearLabel_C1 | Week_C2 | WeekYear_C2 | WeekYearLabel_C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230101 | 1 | 202301 | WYC1 01/2023 | 1 | 202301 | WYC2 01/2023 |
| 20230102 | 1 | 202301 | WYC1 01/2023 | 1 | 202301 | WYC2 01/2023 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 20230108 | 2 | 202302 | WYC1 02/2023 | 1 | 202301 | WYC2 01/2023 |
| 20230109 | 2 | 202302 | WYC1 02/2023 | 2 | 202302 | WYC2 02/2023 |

You end up with a date table with unique dates, but more columns. You will be able to mark this table as a data table, but you have to build up your reports according to the customers calendar, by slicing and filtering the appropriate columns.

This might be a great use case for [field parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-field-parameters).

To transform your existing date table you can use the M query:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Data\example.csv"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Client", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"FYYR", Int64.Type}, {"FYWK", Int64.Type}, {"CORPFYYR", Int64.Type}, {"CORPWK", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Client", "Client2"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Duplicated Column", List.Distinct(#"Duplicated Column"[Client]), "Client2", "FYYR", List.Sum),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Costco", "Costco_FYYR"}, {"Walmart", "Walmart_FYYR"}}),
    #"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Client", "Client2"),
    #"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(#"Duplicated Column1", List.Distinct(#"Duplicated Column1"[Client2]), "Client2", "FYWK", List.Sum),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column1",{{"Costco", "Costco_FYWK"}, {"Walmart", "Walmart_FYWK"}}),
    #"Duplicated Column2" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Client", "Client2"),
    #"Pivoted Column2" = Table.Pivot(#"Duplicated Column2", List.Distinct(#"Duplicated Column2"[Client2]), "Client2", "CORPFYYR", List.Sum),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column2",{{"Walmart", "Walmart_CORPFYYR"}, {"Costco", "Costco_CORPFYYR"}}),
    #"Pivoted Column3" = Table.Pivot(#"Renamed Columns2", List.Distinct(#"Renamed Columns2"[Client]), "Client", "CORPWK", List.Sum),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column3",{{"Costco", "Costco_CORPWK"}, {"Walmart", "Walmart_CORPWK"}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns3", {"Date"}, {
        {"C_FYYR", each List.Max([Costco_FYYR]), Int64.Type}, 
        {"C_FYWK", each List.Max([Costco_FYWK]), Int64.Type}, 
        {"C_CORPFYYR", each List.Max([Costco_CORPFYYR]), Int64.Type}, 
        {"C_CORPWK", each List.Max([Costco_CORPWK]), Int64.Type},
        {"W_FYYR", each List.Max([Walmart_FYYR]), Int64.Type}, 
        {"W_FYWK", each List.Max([Walmart_FYWK]), Int64.Type}, 
        {"W_CORPFYYR", each List.Max([Walmart_CORPFYYR]), Int64.Type}, 
        {"W_CORPWK", each List.Max([Walmart_CORPWK]), Int64.Type}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

I tried it with your example data as a csv:

```
Client;Date;FYYR;FYWK;CORPFYYR;CORPWK
Costco;01-06-2022;2023;1;2022;22
Walmart;01-06-2022;2022;22;2022;22
Costco;02-06-2022;2023;1;2022;22
Walmart;02-06-2022;2022;22;2022;22
Costco;03-06-2022;2023;1;2022;22
Walmart;03-06-2022;2022;22;2022;22
Costco;04-06-2022;2023;1;2022;22
Walmart;04-06-2022;2022;22;2022;22
```

It turns the table from:
[image: Source Format]
to
[image: Transformation applied]

Comment: `You end up with a date table with unique dates, but more rows` - I guess you want to say more columns?

Comment: @variable Yes, I corrected my answer, thank you!

Comment: So with Field parameters there will be 2 slicers per column. For example - 2 slicers for year, and 2 slicers for week. And no relation (cascading) between the choice made for year and week.

Comment: @variable If you need both related, you can easily use WeekYearLabel from my example

Comment: Is there a way to produce the table (as shown in your example) from the table in my question using power query?

Comment: @variable I updated your answer to explain how you might do the transformation in Power BI.